# Lua Max Number Program

Tags: indexing, lua, iteration, lua-table

Here is a short program that takes in a table, and returns the index of the largest numerical value in the table.

My question is - can someone explain to me the "word, count" in the for loop on line 5? The program works, but I am not understanding how the word, count in the for loop does anything.

```
 numbers = {10, 5, 1}

 function largest(t)
   local maxcount = 0
   local maxindex
   for word, count in pairs(t) do
     if count > maxcount then
       maxcount = count
       maxindex = word 
     end
   end
   return maxindex, maxcount
 end

 print(largest(numbers))
```

Comment: The choice of variable names `word`, and `count` is appallingly bad here, especially if this was sample code from a book or tutorial. Much better names would have been `index` (or just `i` or `idx`) and `value`. The code will also do "interesting" things if `largest()` is called with any non-number values. Try `print(largest{"a",3,{13},function()end})` for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following code should make it more clear:

```
tbl = { a = "one", b = "two", c = "two and half" }
for key, val in pairs(tbl) do print(key, val) end
```

When you run `pairs` in a for loop, it executes the code between `do` and `end` once for each key/value pair in the table; `for x, y in` sets the names of the key and value for the code within the loop.  `pairs` is the most commonly seen example of an [iterator](http://www.lua.org/pil/7.1.html).